# Using a pointer to a pointer to a float [3] with sscanf, getting an exception

Tags: c++, exception, pointers, nullpointerexception, scanf

EDIT: Okay since i was too vague earlier heres an SSCCE:

```
typedef float vector[3]

int mainLoaderFunc() {

    char* memory = NULL;
    size_t size = loadFile(fileName, &memory); // load model file into memory, this works, tested and true

    // create vector arrays
    vector *vertexArray = NULL;         
    vector *normalArray = NULL;         
    vector *textureArray = NULL;        

    loadArrays(size, memory, &vertexArray, &normalArray, &textureArray);

    // do other stuff with arrays

}

void loadArrays(size_t size, char *memory, vector **vertexArray, vector **normalArray, vector **textureArray) {

    int numVerts = 0; 
    int numNormals = 0;  
    int numTextures = 0;  

    char* p = memory;           // pointer to start of memory
    char* e = memory + size;    // pointer to end of memory

    // count verts, normals, textures for memory allocation
    while (p != e) {
        if (memcmp(p, "vn", 2) == 0) {
            numNormals++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "vt", 2) == 0) { 
            numTextures++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "v",  1) == 0) {
            numVerts++;
        } 
        while (*p++ != (char) 0x0A);
    }

    // allocate memory for vector arrays
    *vertexArray        = new vector[numVerts];
    *normalArray        = new vector[numNormals];
    *textureArray       = new vector[numTextures];


    int vertexIndex = 0;
    int normalIndex = 0;
    int textureIndex = 0;  //*** IF BREAK POINT HERE: NO EXCEPTION

    // load data from memory into arrays
    while (p != e) {

        if (memcmp(p, "vn", 2) == 0) {
            sscanf(p, "vn %f %f %f", normalArray[normalIndex][0], normalArray[normalIndex][1], normalArray[normalIndex][2]);
            normalIndex++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "vt", 2) == 0) {
            sscanf(p, "vt %f %f", textureArray[textureIndex][0], textureArray[textureIndex][1]);
            textureIndex++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "v", 1) == 0) {
            sscanf(p, "v %f %f %f", vertexArray[vertexIndex][0], vertexArray[vertexIndex][1], vertexArray[vertexIndex][2]);
            vertexIndex++;
        } 
        while (*p++ != (char) 0x0A);
    }

}
```

Once the code hits the sscanf part, i get the exception, i've tried putting &, and * infront of the arrays but i get an exception either way.

Comment: Could you post an actual snippet ([SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)) of your code?

Comment: That's a lot of pointers for C++. Have you considered clearing up your code by creating a `vector` class and using references or (for example) `boost::smart_ptr`s? Also, using `new[]` to allocate memory in your `myFunction` seems confused, why wouldn't you use `new` there?

Comment: Your question is very unclear, and your approach looks horrible from a C++-perspective. If you state your actual intent, we might be able to provide a much safer and simpler solution.

Comment: okay so i added an SSCCE of my code, im using the type def instead of classes and <vector>'s because the libraries in my project use arrays so it was jsut easier at the time.

Comment: This question was recently answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596563/passing-a-triple-pointer-to-allocate-memory-in-another-function-sscanf-exceptio/8596946#8596946).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sscanf` expects a `float *` when using `%f`. `vertexArray` is a `float ***`, `vertexArray[i]` is a `float **`, and `vertexArray[i][j]` is a `float*`. However, this isn't what you want because `vertexArray` is a pointer to an array of `vertex`, so you want to do this instead:

```
&(*vertexArray)[i][j]
```

That will get you the correct `float *` to pass to `sscanf`.

Comment: @eharvest, that's not how `sscanf` works. That's how `printf` works. `sscanf` has to take a pointer, otherwise, it can't write out the `float`!

Comment: sorry it is a mistake... lack of concentration

Answer (score 3):

I guess you have to pass addresses to `sscanf`:

```
sscanf(myMemChunk, "%f %f %f", &myVector[i][0], &myVector[i][1], &myVector[i][2]);
```

Comment: i still get the exception when i do this... maybe the problem isn't what i think it is. I added an SSCCE if that helps.

Comment: This is not correct; you will be passing down `float **` to `sscanf`, not a `float *`.