# Passing a triple pointer to allocate memory in another function, sscanf exception

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, nullpointerexception, scanf

Im allocating memory to a double pointer in another function, therefore I need to use a pointer to the pointer to the pointer. Im getting an exception thrown when i use sscanf, im not sure exactly why. Heres a snippet of the code. This was working earlier when it was all in the same function and i only needed to use double pointers, but now that im refactoring the code and using triple pointers im having this issue.

```
typedef float vector[3]

int mainLoaderFunc() {

    char* memory = NULL;
    size_t size = loadFile(fileName, &memory); // load model file into memory, this works, tested and true

    // create vector arrays
    vector *vertexArray = NULL;         
    vector *normalArray = NULL;         
    vector *textureArray = NULL;        

    loadArrays(size, memory, &vertexArray, &normalArray, &textureArray);

    // do other stuff with arrays

}

void loadArrays(size_t size, char *memory, vector **vertexArray, vector **normalArray, vector **textureArray) {

    int numVerts = 0; 
    int numNormals = 0;  
    int numTextures = 0;  

    char* p = memory;           // pointer to start of memory
    char* e = memory + size;    // pointer to end of memory

    // count verts, normals, textures for memory allocation
    while (p != e) {
        if (memcmp(p, "vn", 2) == 0) {
            numNormals++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "vt", 2) == 0) { 
            numTextures++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "v",  1) == 0) {
            numVerts++;
        } 
        while (*p++ != (char) 0x0A);
    }

    // allocate memory for vector arrays
    *vertexArray        = new vector[numVerts];
    *normalArray        = new vector[numNormals];
    *textureArray       = new vector[numTextures];

    p = memory;

    int vertexIndex = 0;
    int normalIndex = 0;
    int textureIndex = 0;  //*** IF BREAK POINT HERE: NO EXCEPTION

    // load data from memory into arrays
    while (p != e) {

        if (memcmp(p, "vn", 2) == 0) {
            sscanf(p, "vn %f %f %f", &normalArray[normalIndex][0], &normalArray[normalIndex][1], &normalArray[normalIndex][2]);
            normalIndex++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "vt", 2) == 0) {
            sscanf(p, "vt %f %f", &textureArray[textureIndex][0], &textureArray[textureIndex][1]);
            textureIndex++;
        } else if (memcmp(p, "v", 1) == 0) {
            sscanf(p, "v %f %f %f", &vertexArray[vertexIndex][0], &vertexArray[vertexIndex][1], &vertexArray[vertexIndex][2]);
            vertexIndex++;
        } 
        while (*p++ != (char) 0x0A);
    }

}
```

Once the code hits the sscanf part, i get the exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x5e9cf2dc (msvcr100d.dll) in derp.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xcccccccc.
```

Comment: If you're in C++ and you're using triple-pointers, you're almost certainly doing something wrong...

Comment: How does this code ever reach the sscanf part ? Surely you need to reset p to point to memory after the 1st while (p != e) loop, otherwise the 2nd while (p != e) loop won't be entered even once, because it's not reached until p == e.

Comment: Also it is very dangerous to advance p to '\n' (0x0a), then loop back assuming you've not yet reached p == e. Maybe you went right past e looking for '\n'

Comment: id like to use a std::vector of vertex objects, but the opengl and 3d math libraries i've been using use the typedefs as parameters, and i would prefer not to rewrite them.

Comment: oops i left out a line in this example. forgot to put p = memory;

Comment: I think you're off by a level of indirection, i.e. you should have sscanf(..., normalArray[normalIndex][0] ...) instead of &normalArray.  But I agree with the other comments, you definitely need to rethink something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone pointed out, you really shouldn't be using triple pointers here.

Additionally, you might want to do your file scanning as something other than chained if-blocks (or at least split it up into functions).

This should fix your issue, since you only have 2 dereferences where you should have 3:

```
    if (memcmp(p, "vn", 2) == 0) {
        sscanf(p, "vn %f %f %f", &(*normalArray)[normalIndex][0], &(*normalArray)[normalIndex][1], &(*normalArray)[normalIndex][2]);
        normalIndex++;
    } else if (memcmp(p, "vt", 2) == 0) {
        sscanf(p, "vt %f %f", &(*textureArray)[textureIndex][0], &(*textureArray)[textureIndex][1]);
        textureIndex++;
    } else if (memcmp(p, "v", 1) == 0) {
        sscanf(p, "v %f %f %f", &(*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][0], &(*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][1], &(*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][2]);
        vertexIndex++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're passing invalid addresses to `sscanf`. Look at one of your function's arguments:

```
vector **vertexArray
```

`vertexArray` points to the **address of a pointer** passed from `mainLoaderFunc`. `*vertexArray` refers to a pointer to an actual `vector` array, as you realise when you allocate memory for it:

```
*vertexArray = new vector[numVerts];
```

Therefore a valid element in the array would be:

```
(*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][0]
```

Note the `*` which your code is missing; `*vertexArray` refers to the actual array. Now `sscanf` wants an address to this variable, so now get the address of it (extra brackets added for the sake of clarity):

```
&( (*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][0] )
```

Change all your arguments to `sscanf` to be like this one.

Answer (score 1):

You are not dereferencing the vector pointers correctly when passing them to `sscanf()`. Try this instead:

```
if (memcmp(p, "vn", 2) == 0) { 
    sscanf(p, "vn %f %f %f", &((*normalArray)[normalIndex][0]), &((*normalArray)[normalIndex][1]), &((*normalArray)[normalIndex][2])); 
    ++normalIndex; 
} else if (memcmp(p, "vt", 2) == 0) { 
    sscanf(p, "vt %f %f", &((*textureArray)[textureIndex][0]), &((*textureArray)[textureIndex][1])); 
    ++textureIndex; 
} else if (memcmp(p, "v", 1) == 0) { 
    sscanf(p, "v %f %f %f", &((*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][0]), &((*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][1]), &((*vertexArray)[vertexIndex][2])); 
    ++vertexIndex; 
}
```